# Delete cursor and ui elements from Winpe10

Tags: batch-file, user-interface, windows-pe

I want to have a winpe10 build that has no **UI elements** and a cursor. I want to do this because I want a batch file to run on startup **fullscreen** but when this is done I can still see the **cursor** and **verticle scroll bar**. ([Ui elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxPYn.png)) And I also want the alt+tab switcher removed because that is visible when there are more than 1 applications open at the same time ([Switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEvup.png))

**Batch file startup code**

```
@echo off
:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 1                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{F11}"                            >>"%TempVBSFile%
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 1                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
echo Test
pause
```

Is there a way to do all this?

Rasil

Comment: You want to duplicate some CLI-only variant of WinPE? What about just disabling any mouse drivers? Without a mouse or pointing interface, you won't have the mouse cursor. If this isn't an option, perhaps WinPE isn't the right tool for the job? Also, if you could explain what your end goal is, perhaps we can find ways to accomplish that without necessarily going down the path you've chosen.

Comment: @music2myear Yes I would like to have a CLI-only UI that has a batch file of my choice running in full screen. I would like to make it so the end-user cannot exit the batch file alt+tab out or use the mouse cursor. Is there a way to disable the mouse drivers before creating the iso? I have to deploy this os on lots of systems.

Comment: Probably start here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image

Comment: Just looked through the link you sent me but I wasn't able to find a way to uninstall mouse drivers in an offline winpe. The commands they have listed is only for uninstalling 3rd party drivers. Isn't there just a cli only winpe build? I searched for hours but couldn't find a suitable iso to work with.

Comment: There is no variant of desktop Windows that is CLI-only, except a few variants of Windows Server, which are designed for scripted builds and devops/cluster environments. WinPE is simply not designed for what you want to use it for, so you need to readjust your expectations, or find a different tool.